# Express module not found when installed with NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

When I try to run the `app.js` file created by express, I get the following error:

```
$ node app.js

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
```

When I type in `express --version` I get a return statement of `2.3.3`. I used npm to install express. I had to manually make npm using these instructions:

```
git clone http://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```

The error is `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`.

Do I need to do something after installing npm and express in order to make express see the modules created by npm?

- My node is version: 0.4.6
- My express is version: 2.3.3
- My npm is version: 1.0.6

Express is installed globally. I used the `-g` flag to install it.

---

**Edit:** When I try `"node -e require.paths"` I get:

```
[ '/home/user/.node_modules',
  '/home/user/.node_libraries',
  '/usr/local/lib/node' ]
```

So, node isn't detecting the npm installation. How do I get node to detect the npm installation?

Comment: Your question doesn't specify if you have npm >=1.0, but if you don't you should upgrade. When you have done so, you should run `npm install -g express` to install it globally – this is important, since express has its own executable.

Comment: Hello I updated the main post with the versions of node, express, and npm that I am using.

Comment: When you installed express, did you install with `npm install -g express` or just `npm install express`?

Comment: I added the -g argument. At first, I didn't, so I couldn't check the version of express installed using -g. Now, I am able to run commands using express in the shell. I typed: sudo npm install -g express

Comment: NPM global modules are installed to `/usr/local/lib/node/`, so it is looking for them. Check the directories to make sure that the directories were actually created correctly. Also, what do you get from `npm ls -s express`?

Comment: npm > 1.0 no longer installs global modules to /usr/local/lib/node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. This worked for me though:

Seems like npm (now?) installs node modules to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` and not `/usr/local/lib/node/`

What I did was simply to copy everything from node_modules to node: `sudo cp -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/* usr/local/lib/node/` and now it seems to be working for me.

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you'll need copy any new modules from /usr/local/lib/node_modules to /usr/local/lib/node every time you install something using npm.

Comment: Nooo, don't do this! So... ugly!

Comment: This is super nasty but I just created a symlink `ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node`. It's a tiny bit cleaner.

Answer (score 72):

- Install express

  `npm install -g express`
- Create a new app

  `express your_app`
- cd into app directory

  `cd your_app`
- use npm link to resolve modules

  `npm link express`

Comment: I got `npm ERR! Error: npm link not supported on windows` :(

Comment: Yes, the joy of windows :)

Comment: @RenatoGama Windows 7 supports symbolic links via mklink.

Comment: is this now the standard way of making global packages available to apps?

Comment: @JCM What should I exactly link? I tried to add a link from my_app folder to the `[pathto_nodejs]\node_modules\express`, but the module is still not found.

Comment: @ADC What is the NPM version that you are using?

Answer (score 28):

Use local installs for require(), and global installs for command-line apps.

If you need both, use the `npm link` command.

Answer (score 20):

On Ubuntu 12.04 you have to add the `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to your /.bashrc to use globally installed modules.

Comment: This is by far the cleanest and most elegant solution. This should work on most Linux and OS X installations

Comment: Im my case, was `export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules"` because I'm using a different node than from Ubuntu repositories. But your is a good (or best) anwser here.

Comment: This fixed it for me on macOS

Answer (score 15):

It appears that while npm had been updated to install global modules into `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, Node's own `require.paths` does not yet reflect this change.

There are two reasonable solutions:

1. Add the following code to the top of your application:

   ```
   require.paths.push('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');
   ```

   - Pro: non-invasive, easy to add
   - Con: requires discipline, future versions of node *will* restrict access to `require.paths`
2. As root, execute:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node
   ```

   - Pro: reasonably non-invasive
   - Con: requires root, modifies linux fs, might not survive system updates

Comment: Remember to either `rmdir /usr/local/lib/node` first or add the force flag: `ln -sf /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node`

Comment: i agree with your conclusion but the suggestion here is along the same lines and better http://stackoverflow.com/a/11887453/124486

Answer (score 8):

What about `NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules` in *.bashrc* or *.bash_profile*? I think it's the real correct way.

Comment: this is a good trick when you want to test something in a project, for example I had the marmalade-repo project and wanted to test mongo interactions from the projects library:

    NODE_PATH=~/node_modules/marmalade/node_modules ~/noderoot/bin/node

gets it done.

Answer (score 2):

It may happen, if you're using windows, that the environment variable `NODE_PATH` is not set, and thus when you execute `node fileName.js` it won't find the libraries.

Check for the variable on your console, and if not present, create it. Give it the `NODE_HOME\node_modules` value, where `NODE_HOME` is your node install dir. This path is where npm install puts every module upon downloading.

Answer (score 2):

Set `NODE_PATH=NODE_HOME\node_modules`.

I'm using windows 7 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`require.paths` is removed, use the `NODE_PATH` environment variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the easiest way to do this is to run `npm install` from your app's folder. This tells npm to hook everything up.

It's the last instruction after `express <appname>`:

```
...
dont forget to install dependencies:
$ cd <appname> && npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally with Linux a good way to do is to use the command : `sudo apt-get install node-express`

But with express 4 we must use express-generator to make app skeleton, install it with 'npm install express-generator -g', and then run 'express myapp' command. 
see also [install express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html)

Answer (score 0):

For all problems with express with a mac computer:

The solution is:

1. `chown` to your user the .npm folder :

   ```
   sudo chown -R Webmaste /Users/webmaste/.npm/
   ```
2. At your test folder or your folder:

   ```
   sudo npm install -g express@2.5.8
   ```
3. Invoke express from your actual location:

   ```
   /usr/local/share/npm/bin/express
   ```
4. `sudo cd . && npm install`
5. Finally:

   ```
   node app
   ```

---

the final message in the console should look like this:

> `Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode`

Answer (score 0):

for mac users

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node
sudo ln -s ../node_modules/* ./$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `gulp` and when I ran this `gulp` command in the command line I got a `gulp: command not found` error. It appeared that it installed `gulp` in my local folder that is `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.node/lib/node_modules` and not in the global `npm` folder.

You can check `npm` root folder by running this command: `npm root -g`, which was returning my personal directory `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.node/lib/node_modules` and not the expected `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

You can fix this by running `npm config set prefix /usr/local` command.