# AWS Elastic Beanstalk , cannot install node.js private module hosted on bitbucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a node.js application to Elastic Beanstalk.

In my main package.json I have a private module hosted on Bitbucket.

```
"dependencies": {
"my-module": "git+https://<API-KEY>:x-oauth-basic@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git"}
```

You can see this case as reference : [NPM private git module on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869796/npm-private-git-module-on-heroku/29677091#29677091)

Once I do my : `eb deploy`

My npm installation fails marking the following error :

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org- <team>-my-module-git-ac810b24
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24: Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24:
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24: and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Linux 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.2-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.2-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<team>/my-module.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-<team>-my-module-git-ac810b24'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log
```

I don't get why is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error `Permission denied (publickey).` from bitbucket. The Elasticbeanstalk part is fine, it just doesn't have permission to download your private repo. You'll have to get your public key into Bitbucket or use HTTP auth.

Comment: The issue I think is more related to Bitbucket or npm that is trying to use publickey (git+ssh) instead of (git+https)