# Heroku update repo-dependencies?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I used [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353408/1446048) to add a private git repo "Foo" as a dependency in a Node.js project "Bar" on Heroku.

Suppose I push an update to that repo Foo, but Bar is unchanged.

Is there a way to have Heroku update/pull Foo?

At the moment the only way I've found is to make a trivial change to to Bar, `commit --amend --no-edit && push -f` in order to keep a clean history.. There's surely a better way?

Comment: you would do `git submodule update`

Comment: @FredericHenri It's not a submodule