# How to deploy project with private dependency from bitbucket in package.json

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, bitbucket

I have the project in node.js. And this main project has the dependency in package.json from private bitbucket repository. So the problem is how to set this dependency that it can be deployed on my host Heroku?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869796/npm-private-git-module-on-heroku

Comment: thank you, Will, for the valuable tip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This decision works excellent for me

**App passwords (Bitbucket)**
App passwords are primarily intended as a way to provide compatibility with apps that don't support two-factor authentication, and you can use them for this purpose as well. First, [create an app password](https://bitbucket.org/account/admin/app-passwords), then specify your dependency like this:

```
"dependencies" : {
    "my-module": "git+https://<username>:<app-password>@bitbucket.org/my_bitbucket_account/my_repo.git"
}
```

Comment: How is putting the app password in a file that is not being ignored is an answer? this is not a good answer, this lacks the security aspect.