# Heroku: How to deploy a NodeJS app with a private repo dependency?

Tags: node.js, heroku, package.json, ssh-keys, buildpack

I want to deploy a NodeJS app on Heroku that has a private repository listed as a dependency in `package.json`.

How do I grant Heroku read-only access to this single repository, without exposing any credentials unnecessarily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been asked repeatedly in various forms, but I was unable to get any of the answers working.

Here is what finally did the trick — Note that I am on Windows 10:

- Generate key in git bash with the command `ssh-keygen -t ssh-rsa -C "myusername@protonmail.com"` (empty password)
- Copy & paste the `*.pub` file (created by the above command) contents as a deploy key here: https://github.com/myusername/my-private-repo/settings/keys
- `my-private-repo` above refers to the dependency, not the repo you are deploying
- On Heroku, add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ssh-key.git as a buildpack — **ABOVE** — the heroku/nodejs buildpack
- Set your Heroku app's environment variable `BUILDPACK_SSH_KEY` to the — **ENTIRE** — contents of the other file (not the one ending with `.pub`) including the NEWLINE at the end (not sure if that's optional)
- Set dependency URL in `package.json` like so:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "my-private-repo": "git+ssh://github.com/myusername/my-private-repo.git"
  }
```

Happy deploying

Comment: Thank youuuuuu I've been searching for hours for this. +1

Comment: what about if we want to use multiple private repos from the same organization, what would the BUILDPACK_SSH_KEY look like?