# How to pull MULTIPLE private repos from GitHub when deploying Heroku app?

Tags: github, heroku, repository, ssh-keys, deploy-keys

How can I deploy a Heroku app with **multiple** `package.json` dependencies that are private repositories?

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69923109/13378247) past answer of mine explains how to use a GitHub deploy key on a private repository to enable a Heroku app to pull it as a `package.json` dependency.

But, the same deploy key can't be used on more than one repository.  And the Heroku buildpack used in the linked answer appears to only support a single deploy key.

Comment: Might want to look into [GemFury](https://gemfury.com/) or similar