# express not installed on my machine

Tags: node.js, express, nodeclipse

I downloaded node.js onto my linux fedora core 18 machine.
After that using npm -g install express installed express. The problem is I am unable to find the express file to be supplied to Nodeclipse in the preference.

Hence, my application using express is not able to compile saying express not found. 
Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Why not just npm install express?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919629/express-module-not-found-when-installed-with-npm

Answer (score 1):

try installing it with this command and see if it works:

```
npm install -g express
```

then go to cd myapp

```
npm link express
```

this could do the trick..

Comment: The problem is that `NODE_HOME` is not set for any global location by default, not that the authors does not use a `-g` key, which he does. -1

Answer (score 0):

Nodeclipse is using `express` executable only for wizard. Everything else works as for node.js from command line (try `node myapp.js`)

As advised by @isaacs in [Express module not found when installed with NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919629/express-module-not-found-when-installed-with-npm), do `npm install express` for local project folder.